# Can't import cx_oracle in python3 on debian 7.11

Tags: python-3.x, cx-oracle

I'm having trouble importing cx_Oracle into python3 on debian 7.11. I know it's old-stable, but I am restricted to this version until we migrate some services in production to servers with newer debian. The error I'm getting follows:

```
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/cx_Oracle.cpython-32mu.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicode_GET_LENGTH
```

Python 3 was installed from official wheezy repos, no third parties. cx_oracle was installed using pip-3.2. Please point me in right direction.

Comment: Provide the version of cx_Oracle you are using if the answer below doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to use a newer version of cx_Oracle with an old version of Python. You'll want to try a newer version of Python (which you'll have to download and compile yourself) or you'll want to try an older version of cx_Oracle that still had support for Python 3.2.

Comment: Thank you, I've used older version of cx_Oracle and it now works fine.